# add support for pasting images

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, imgur, uploader

I was very happy to learn that you had added support for directly uploading images to imgur.  However, I would like to see this taken one step further, if it is even possible.

Today, if I want to upload a screen shot (and let's face it, this is probably the most likely case in the computing-related stackexchange sites), I need to take the shot, paste it into an image editor, save the file and then upload to imgur via SO, and delete it when the upload completes.

If possible, I suggest adding a mechanism to *paste* an image directly into the question (or answer) and have SO automatically create a temporary file, upload to imgur and make the link.  This would save many annoying steps when posting screenshots.

Comment: I highly doubt this sort of integration is possible with today's technology.

Comment: @TimYiJiang HTML 5 HTML 5 HTML 5

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail \*looks at calendar* Hey, it's only \*yawn* 2 years late!

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: I'm in no rush :-)

Comment: @ChrisF how is this status-completed? I've attempted pasting a few different forms of images (pixel data in clipboard, file name in clipboard, url in clipboard) with no luck.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - OK. I was reacting to a flag and thought that it was completed as the upload image dialog has "(or paste or drag-and-drop)" on it which I've successfully used. However, if the consensus is that it's not fully implemented I'll revert the edit.

Comment: Pasting is already possible, but you need to open the "add image" popup from the editor or by pressing CTRL+G. Just as I posted the comment, status-completed..

Comment: Doesn't work for me (tested it in chrome/firefox); pasting the same image on imgur.com worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

We added the ability to paste an image into the file upload dialog some time ago:

[image]

Comment: so selfless to refund the bounty rather than let it award to you :)

Comment: @mhlester selfless? more like [shameless copy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168763/152859)! ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This Anna Lear character should be suspended for plagiarism.

Comment: You can always suspend yourself! This should be fun experience, I'm sure. :D

Comment: This [feature was "disabled"](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink?view=revision&revision=168494) in the most recent update of Google Chrome. Is there a fix planned on SE's side?

Answer (score 0):

Imgur does have [some tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWRAL.jpg) that might streamline this process for you.

The "Hyperdesktop - Screenshot Uploader" sounds more like what would fit in with your current workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible yet in any sort of reliable consistent way. There are methods of doing it, but the system is still in enough flux and variations between platforms are just enough of a hassle that I don't think the SE devs should be spending their time working that out. There are more important things that we can't find on our end that we need from them.

Until such a time as this is an easy feature to add, you should streamline your work flow with a tool for the job. There are lots of screenshot utilities that make the process of taking, editing and posting a shot much simpler. A likely place to look is the extension system for your browser. I have one that allows me to take a screen shot of either page *or* screen content and post it to Imgur in one easy step.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219197/how-to-manage-image-pasting-from-clipboard-in-html5 :)

Comment: @TheCommunity I didn't say impossible, I said said it wasn't reliable and consistent yet. Until it is, there are better things the SE devs could be putting their time too.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally I'm glad it's been added; I'm hoping "early" adoption by a major network like SE will be useful for identifying pitfalls, refining the standard, working out inconsistencies, etc.

Comment: As part of the last image uploader update, you can paste when the image upload box is up, if your browser supports it.  It isn't supported directly in the editor because we don't want to auto-upload a picture you didn't want going to imgur on an accidental Ctrl+V of what you thought was text for example.  Uploading of an image, we feel, should be a very conscious decision.