# Upload images by drag-and-drop

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, uploader, drag-and-drop

Some image hosting sites like Imgur and min.us support image uploading via drag-and-drop in Chrome and Firefox. It would be nice if you could upload an image and add it to your post by dropping it on the edit page.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A few days ago (February 2011), a new image upload is being tested on Meta, adding support for paste and drag-and-drop:

[image: New image upload dialog]

However, this does not support direct paste or drag-and-drop into the edit page; one first needs to click the "Image" button (Ctrl+G) to show the upload dialog.

In June 2015, this new dialog was implemented:

[image: Newer image upload dialog]

Comment: But: [no direct download from xkcd.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152504/have-a-checkmark-to-turn-an-imgurled-web-image-into-a-link-to-the-original-auto) ;-)

Comment: And: maybe it's part of A/B Testing, [just like a new sign up form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/161595/20).

Comment: It's not, but it hasn't been deployed beyond Meta yet either. Can't wait for it to show up in chat...

Comment: @shog9, if this post is too early, then of course feel free to delete (and also in the Recent Changes post, and some comments). It works great, by the way!

Comment: I don't see any reason not to document it - I'm pretty sure this isn't going away, and it could probably use some more attention (and stress-testing) before it goes live elsewhere anyway.

Comment: It _does_ allow pasting images

Comment: Sure, @badp, *after* you first clicked the "Image" button (Ctrl+G). In Chrome on a Mac, I cannot paste directly into the editor, which is what the question kind of asked for. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: `or paste or drag-and-drop` sounds wrong. Replace the second "or" with a slash, like this: `or paste/drag-and-drop`

Comment: Very cool guys! Best/Website/Ever ;)

Comment: (@Shog9 and all: I noticed it's live on SO as well; please feel free to delete this when the team makes some official announcement here!)