# Add option to upload image directly from the clipboard

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

I've seen this question: [Add an image directly from the clipboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/add-an-image-directly-from-the-clipboard) however with HTML5 some browsers support this:

http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/

Can this be added, pretty please?