# Have a checkmark to turn an imgurl'ed web image into a link to the original automatically (default=on)

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur

While it's a convenient feature to have an image from [somewhere in the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/) be automatically cloned to the (hopefully) permanent i.stack.imgur.com, automatically turning the image into a link to the original (or it's source, which might even be auto-determined for some sites like Wikipedia, maybe even automating correct attribution) would help for correct attribution and further research on that image's source site (instead of having to use e.g. [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/) first). Something like this maybe:

[image: mockup]

**Clarification**: The image would still be uploaded to imgur, but in addition its markdown would be a hyperlink to the source (or e.g. its dedicated Wikimedia page).

Comment: Bonus points for adding a third tab `from xkcd.com` where entering the number automatically adds a `[![](https://sslimgs.xkcd.com/comics/NAME.png)](https://xkcd.com/NUMBER/ "hover text")`

Comment: A new upload is being tested, but that also doesn't have a direct link to xkcd.com ;-)

Comment: I wonder if there's any "standard" HTML thing (like [microdata](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html)) for this. Just a link might still not make it easier for the copyright owner to find linked copies.

Comment: Wikimedia's URL structure aside, what would such image URL tell the user who clicks that? For most URLs it would only reveal the website domain but not, for example, on which specific page(s) [an image](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/native-image-uploads-imgur.png) was used, or who created the image?

Comment: @Arjan Good point, and adding another "Site where you found this [optional]" would probably overcomplicate the dialogue... But anyway it's easier to image-google for that URL (first hit: [check](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/)) then having to first correctly determine where this specific version came from. Plus this way the image owner can use google to find SE sites using their image.

Answer (score 1):

I can get where you're coming from... but I think any user who understands web concepts well enough to get what that feature means would be comfortable editing the Markup manually.

It merits note that the StackExchange network isn't just for developers anymore; will it be that easy for someone on `cooking.stackexchange.com` to understand what this option does? Or will it just seem confusing?

Comment: Time it takes to notice the checkmark: 0.03s. Time it takes to edit the Markup: "Let's see... `[![](http://url)](http://url)`..." even copy-pasting on a US keyboard where `[]` doesn't require two keys, at least 2s. Every-Time. And no-one _does_.

Comment: But the StackExchange network isn't just for developers anymore; will it be that easy for someone on cooking.stackexchange.com? Or will it just seem confusing?

Comment: Isn't that rather a _pro_ reason? Since you mention cooking.SE, someone including a Wikipedia image to show what [Kohlrabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrabi) looks like may not even know that their link is turned into an imgur upload, so this might actually _de_-crease confusion.

Comment: No, adding more settings they don't understand does not de-crease confusion ;)