# Why is paste/drag-and-drop of images not available on some browsers?

Tags: support, images, browsers

Since [February 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/168244), Stack Exchange has been offering [paste/drag-and-drop insertion of images into posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80201/168244). This is awesome, but it doesn't work the same on all browsers.

Google Chrome (28.0.1500.71 m) provides both paste & drag-and-drop (this feature seems to have been removed in 35.0.1916.114 m):

[image: Chrome 'add image']

Firefox (22.0) only provides drag-and-drop:

[image: Firefox 'add image']

Internet Explorer (9.0.8112.16421) provides none:

[image: Internet Explorer 'add image']

Why is there a deficiency in certain browsers and/or what can be done?

Comment: Yes I am interested too.

Comment: @Dims: Running Chrome is much more convenient with the copy-and-paste feature.

Comment: Yes, but it is a magic. I would like to know what is the real problem with pasting in other browsers.

Comment: @Dims: That's why I haven't accepted the current "answer", since it doesn't provide an answer to the question "why". I can't see why "browser compatibility" could be considered the problem, since technology nowadays seem to be so transferable. I don't know much about it, but thought these things would be ubiquitous across browsers due to its simplicity... I've been performing copy-and-paste since, like, forever.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2031588#2031588

Comment: This change in Chrome sucks, considering open sourcing Stack Exchange and taking pull requests in order to fix

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with browser compatibility.

None of the mobile browsers support it either.

Seems like IE9 specifcally uses a different API then other browsers

[Internet Explorer 9 Drag and Drop (DnD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500615/internet-explorer-9-drag-and-drop-dnd)

Comment: So if IE9 uses a "different API", why is there not a similar one for IE9 that allows pasting? And what about Firefox not allowing pasting? Does it mean that the technology just doesn't exist for those browsers? Why is Google Chrome so special that it can do/allow both? I know nothing about these things, hence all the questions, sorry...

Comment: @Werner try googling for HTML5 drag and drop and paste API or something I am sure there is a lot of content out there. HTML5ROCKS is a great resource

Comment: So what browser should DO in order to be able to paste?

Comment: So if I change user agent string in Firefox to Chrome it will be able to paste?

Comment: @raam86 so Chrome does not paste anymore and the question persists: what browser should DO in order to paste?

Comment: @Dims They should implement HTML5 drag and drop api natively...