# Websocket connection error on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, web-sockets

Using Chrome, I am having this error when I refresh a page on Stack Overflow and open the developer tool:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/' failed: Unexpected response code: 502 full.js?v=f9e9cb812ede:13

PS. Also, the copy/pasting feature does not work when you try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste a print screen.

Chrome version: 29.0.1547.62 m

OS: Windows 7

[image]

Comment: `Also copy/pase feature does not work when you try to Ctrl+v to pase a print screen` - considering the editor is a text editor, that is not surprising.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't get your point, I am using a chrome widget that I used to use in stackoverflow without issues.

Comment: What psubsee2003 is saying, is that Control-V is not *supposed* to work as a way to paste images into a SE question. If you have an extension/widget that is meant to provide that functionality, and it's not working, well, you should maybe bring that up with the widget author.

Comment: I get these from time to time as well. It is either your internet dropping packets, or theirs hitting some sort of connection limit at times. Either way, I have never noticed it to have more of an impact than the warning/error messages themselves. Your post script (PS) is not relevant to this topic.

Comment: @psubsee2003 it does work when you open the image upload dialog and click CTRL+V - it's supported only by Chrome though and [was added pretty recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168763/152859). :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but it is a Chrome feature or a SE feature?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Stack Exchange feature, added by demand. Guess it's using HTML5 feature available only in Chrome.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - We actually feature detect here. And yes, at the moment, only Chrome seems to support it.

Comment: @Oded you mean [this](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/clipops/clipops.html#fire-a-clipboard-event)? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - indeed