# When I paste a URL auto upload it same way raw binary image is being uploaded

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader, paste

For some time now, we can [paste a picture from clipboard directly to the image upload dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80201/152859). (Chrome only, as far as I can tell)

Great, and I'm now using this instead of storing all the pictures on my disk when creating mockups or adding free hand circles to existing images. :)

Since the paste event is already handled, and image already being sent to imgur server for processing, can it please be extended so that when I paste valid URL (just need to check protocol actually) it can go through the same steps, saving two clicks?

Comment: And pressing Enter should confirm the dialog ;P

Comment: @OliverSalzburg well, actually I think it already does! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. At least not after pasting a raw image from the clipboard.