# Drag and drop for images

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Why don't just allow for drag and drop upload of images directly on the editing area, without the need for using the upload image tool?

Currently if one just drags and drops the path of the file il displayed and not the image.

Comment: That would be convenient, actually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload images by drag-and-drop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80201/upload-images-by-drag-and-drop)

Comment: @Laurel although the dupe question is similar if not the same, the answer there can;t be applied here. OP asks explicitly for a drag-drop option without having to use the Image Uploader. It is not a duplicate IMO.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207756/when-i-paste-a-url-auto-upload-it-same-way-raw-binary-image-is-being-uploaded.