# Add copy+paste to chat image upload

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, uploader

The post editor image uploader supports drag-and-drop and it also supports pasting an image directly into the window.

The chat uploader does support drag-and-drop (as long as you drop directly into the filename text box) but does not support pasting an image into the window.

Can chat get the same [upload dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80201/upload-images-by-drag-and-drop) that the sites have?

Comment: Turns out it's a dupe. Let's all go bug people there!